# Can we dynamically check if npot is supported in android?

Tags: android

Is there a way to query if the OpenGL ES implementation on android supports non-power of two textures?

Comment: I realize this other question came after, but it has an accepter answer - hence dupe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705753/android-opengl-es-loading-a-non-power-of-2-texture

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this reported in the extensions string before as "GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two". E.g. on the emulator if you call:

```
gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS)
```

Where gl is your GL10 instance, then you get:

```
GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_query_matrix GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ANDROID_direct_texture GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap
```

Which has that extension listed, so the emulator supports non power of two sized textures.